# WKWebView iOS 10.3 crash for didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge?

Tags: ios, iphone, authentication, wkwebview, ios10.3

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {
    var user: String?
    var password: String?
    switch providerID {
    case "197": // ABC Stagging
        user = "ABC"
        password = "abc"
    default:
        break
    }
    if let user = user, password = password {
        let credential = NSURLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistence.ForSession)
        challenge.sender?.useCredential(credential, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, credential)
    }
}
```

According to crashlytics crash is happening on line with info ***The challenge was not sent by the receiver.***

```
    challenge.sender?.useCredential(credential, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)
```

Any help is appreciated. This happens only on iOS 10.3. I guess some users have beta and are experiencing this.

Comment: Did any one get the issue resolved ? I am facing the same issue. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same problem for me, I fixed it by commented this line

```
//    challenge.sender?.useCredential(credential, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)
```

Comment: Yup that is what I did as well.

Comment: We should be able to set credentials

Comment: Did any one get the issue resolved ? I am facing the same issue. Please help. Commenting the line doesn't help

Comment: By commenting the line how you are sending credentials now ??

Comment: You can send credentials by adding them to request URL. For example http://login:password@your.page.com

Comment: For me, in iOS 10.3.3. and iOS 11.0.2, commenting that line out stops the crash, but produces an endless didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge loop.

Comment: Commenting this line and keeping 
``completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, credential)`` fixed it for me